# Tricky LINQ query for text file format transformation

Tags: c#, linq

I have a shopping list in a text file, like this:

```
BuyerId    Item;
1;         Item1;
1;         Item2;
1;         ItemN;
2;         Item1;
2;         ItemN;
3;         ItemN;
```

I need to transform this list to a format like this:

```
Item1; Item2; Item3; ...; ItemN    <--- For buyer 1
Item1; ...; ItemN                  <--- For buyer 2
Item1; ...; ItemN                  <--- For buyer 3
```

First I parse the CSV file like this:

```
IList<string[]> parsedcsv = (from line in lines.Skip(1) 
                             let parsedLine = line.TrimEnd(';').Split(';')
                             select parsedLine).ToList();
```

Then I group the items with LINQ and aggregate them to the final format:

```
IEnumerable<string> buyers = from entry in parsedcsv
                             group entry by entry[0] into cart
                             select cart.SelectMany(c => c.Skip(1))
                                  .Aggregate((item1, item2) => 
                                      item1 + ";" + item2).Trim();
```

HOWEVER, as it happens, the BuyerId is not unique, but repeats after a number of times (for example, it can repeat like this: 1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3 or like this 1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2).

No big deal, I could quite easily fix this by grouping the items in a loop that checks that I only deal with one buyer at a time:

```
int lastBatchId = 0;
string currentId = parsedcsv[0][0];
for (int i = 0; i < parsedcsv.Count; i++)
{
    bool last = parsedcsv.Count - 1 == i;
    if (parsedcsv[i][0] != currentId || last)
    {
         IEnumerable<string> buyers = from entry in parsedcsv.Skip(lastBatchId)
              .Take(i - lastBatchId + (last ? 1 : 0))
         ...
         lastBatchId = i;
         currentId = parsedcsv[i][0];
         ...
```

... however, this is not the most elegant solution. I'm almost certain this can be done only with LINQ.

Can anyone help me out here please ?

Thanks!

Comment: "the buyer with ID = 1 is not the same buyer as the buyer after the buyer with ID = 3." - What is that sentence supposed to mean?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Later on: "HOWEVER, as it happens, the BuyerId is not unique, but repeats after a number of times (for example, it can repeat like this: 1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3 or like this 1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2)."

Comment: So, the *value*  of the Buyer ID is irrelevant. The only thing that is relevant is the change from one Buyer ID to the next. In that case the loop most certainly is the best way to do this.

Comment: How I read your question, your linq query actually already does what you want.

Comment: Are you saying buyerID 1, when it appears again, needs to go under a different category (ie, he should really have a new number)? If that's the case it might be worth checking for existence and then reassigning somehow.

Comment: @Daniel - Sorry, this sentance was not supposed to be there. Corrected now.

Yes, the code already does what I need it to do. All I wanted was to (just for the fun of it) rewrite it as a single LINQ query without an external loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the best solution, but you said you want a pure Linq answer, so here you have it:

```
var result = from r in (

    from l in lines.Skip(1)
    let data = l.Split(new string[]{";"," "}, 
                       StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    select new { Id = data.First(), Item = data.Skip(1).First() })
    .Aggregate(new 
                { 
                    Rows = Enumerable.Repeat(new 
                                            { 
                                                Id = string.Empty, 
                                                Items = new List<string>() 
                                            }, 1).ToList(), 
                    LastID = new List<string>() { "" } 
                }, 
                (acc, x) => 
                { 
                    if (acc.Rows[0].Id == string.Empty)
                        acc.Rows.Clear();
                    if (acc.LastID[0] != x.Id)
                        acc.Rows.Add(new 
                                    {
                                        Id = x.Id, 
                                        Items = new List<string>() 
                                    });
                    acc.Rows.Last().Items.Add(x.Item);
                    acc.LastID[0] = x.Id;
                    return acc; 
                }       
    ).Rows
select new 
{ 
    r.Id, 
    Items = string.Join(";", from x in r.Items 
                             select x) 
};
```

I wrote it pretty fast and it could be improved, I don't like it particularly because it resorts to a couple of tricks, but it's pure Linq and could be a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at [GroupAdjacent](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/GroupAdjacent.cs?r=fb6fc90407fc5af44485e9062d0c6f06606e1d10).

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for a pure LINQ solution.